# Why cannot add an ArrayList<String> into an ArrayList<Object>?

Tags: java, object, arraylist

This is kinda working:

```
    ArrayList<Object> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
    list1.add("Hello");
    list1.add(1.5);
    list1.add(new Whatever());
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> listAll = new ArrayList<>();
    listAll.add(list1);
```

In an ArrayList of Object you can add any Object... also you can add the same ArrayList with Objects into another ArrayList of Object. Why is this not working:

```
    ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
    list1.add("Hello");
    list1.add(new String("World!"));
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> listAll = new ArrayList<>();
    listAll.add(list1);
```

I have an ArrayList of Strings (String is an Object) and I cannot add these although these are Objects in `listAll`.

*PS: JDK1.7*

Edit: Well I do read this 'duplicate', about Dogs and Cats. Not sure I got it, but alright :)

Comment: Because generics type are invariant. `List<String>` is not a subtype of `List<Object>`.

Comment: @silla in your first example, `ArrayList<Object>` is an `ArrayLst<Object>` (obviously) but in your second example `ArrayList<String>` is not an `ArrayList<Object>`.

Answer (score 0):

Everything here is an instance of Object but reverse isn't true.

```
(String is an Object but Object is not String)
```

That is the reason ArrayList of type string will not accept Object but only String.

Comment: You are wrong: in the example above, an ArrayList<String> should be added to an ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>. The real reason is referred to in the comment of assylias